# Function not firing when AC button pressed

Tags: javascript

I have a masterFunction which should fire another function called reset when the AC button on my calculator is pressed (picked up via e.target.id = "AC").

However it's not firing, in fact no functions are firing when I press the AC button.

I've added a console log and can see e.target.id = "AC" yet it still won't fire.

Reduced code:

```
//Update display with button clicked
buttonGrid.addEventListener('click', e => {
console.log(e.target.id);
    masterFunction(e);
});

//Fire relevant function depending on the button pressed etc
let masterFunction = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === "AC")  {
        reset(e);
    } 
}; 

// Reset the screen
  let reset = (e) => {
    secondNumberCounter = false;
    operatorPressed = false;
    firstNumber = 0;
    secondNumber = 0;
    buttonNumber = 0;
    decimalCounter = 0;
    displayArea.textContent = 0;
  };
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/2s9nuLj0/5/

Comment: What is the meaning of `e` in `reset`?

Comment: Define "not firing".  When you step through the code in your browser's script debugger, which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?  What are the runtime values used in that operation?  What is the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Your `masterFunction` is being triggered twice, that is not going to be good.

Comment: @SamJefferies: Please [learn how to use a JavaScript debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3u2groOG-A). This will solve 75% of your problems, and for the other 25%, it will give you the information to put into your question that makes the question actually useful and easy to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because your first if condition is eating up the clicks. Basic debugging will show your problem.

```js
    console.log('BEFORE THE IFS');
    if (operatorPressed === false && firstNumberCounter === true && e.target.dataset.type != "nonNumberFunction") { 
        console.log('I AM HERE!!!!')
        firstNumberPicker(e);
    }
```

and you should stop the default action of the clicks

```js
buttonGrid.addEventListener('click', e => {
    masterFunction(e);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks what does e.preventDefault do exactly? Does this need to be defined as an actual function?

Also how come that section eats up the clicks when e.target.dataset.type != "nonNumberFunction" is present?

Comment: well figure out why it goes in there. `console.log(operatorPressed === false, firstNumberCounter === true, e.target.dataset.type != "nonNumberFunction"); console.log(operatorPressed, firstNumberCounter, e.target.dataset.type);` Debugging is key to figuring out why things do not work. It will be clear when you see why it goes in there.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Thanks bud, still not sure why you've included e.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: Add console.log stamement in the onclick and see what happens when you click the buttons. Now add the preventDefault and do the same thing. Notice anything different?